# An autoformat tool to automatically insert braces around single-line clauses?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

So assuming that in our work environment we've decided that the One True Faith forbids this:

```
if (something) 
    doSomething();
```

And instead we want:

```
if (something) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Is there a tool that will do that automagically?  Awesomest would be to have eclipse just do it, but since we're really just recovering from one ex-employee that thought he was too pretty for coding conventions, a less-friendly tool that would do it right just once would suffice.

Comment: So is this a Java specific question or does this apply to other languages where blocks are a part of the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can set this in Eclipse's formatting rules and run the built-in formatter.. e.g. the "Use blocks" option:

[image: Code Style Tab]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-clean/CodeStyle.jpg))</sub>

Of course, you need the rest of the formatting options to be set how you want them, since I don't think you can selectively apply only a single rule/option..

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it's actually not a formatter, but a "Clean Up":
Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up

And then to execute.  Source -> Clean Up
As opposed to Source -> Format

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [GreatCode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgreatcode/) can do this for you (along with a ton of other options)